# How to point to custom folder in configuration block in pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven

I have `application.properties` in /etc folder like this: `etc/project/application.properties`, but I can't find a way how to point to it inside pom.xml configuration section.

So far I have:

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <configFiles>
                        <configFile>/etc/project/application.properties</configFile> //<-- does not work!
                    </configFiles>
                </configuration>
     ...
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

See [Flyway Maven plugin, Config files](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/maven/#config-files):

> It is also possible to point Flyway at one or more additional config files. This is achieved by supplying the System property `flyway.configFiles` as follows:
>
> ```
> $ mvn -Dflyway.configFiles=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf flyway:migrate
> ```
>
> To pass in multiple files, separate their names with commas:
>
> ```
> $ mvn -Dflyway.configFiles=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf,other.conf flyway:migrate
> ```

So, contrary to the usual Maven convention `configFiles` is the name of the property, not a collection of properties:

```xml
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <flyway.configFiles>/etc/project/application.properties</flyway.configFiles>  <!-- this should work -->
                    <!-- <configFiles>/etc/project/application.properties</configFiles> -->  <!-- or this -->
                </configuration>
```

If neither works try:

```xml
    <properties>
        <flyway.configFiles>/etc/project/application.properties</flyway.configFiles>
    <properties>
```

Comment: For some reason it adds /User/me/current/project/location up front. like so: –```/User/me/current/project/location/etc/project/application.properties```, not just ```/etc/project/application.properties```

Comment: @AverageJoe9000 What if you remove the leading "`/`"?

Comment: it gives exception, stating that ```Unable to load config from /Users/me/Projects/my_project/etc/project/application.properties```

Comment: @AverageJoe9000 Please add the exception stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

accroding to flyway maven plugin’s official doc: [flyway maven plugin  doc](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/maven/#config-files)

you can supplying the System property flyway.configFiles as follows:

`$ mvn -Dflyway.configFiles=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf flyway:migrate`

or use the FLYWAY_CONFIG_FILES environment variable

Comment: Setting properties on the command line or inside a POM shouldn't matter. They both are properties after all. It has to be the correct property name in the POM, of course.